# How to relate prevalence to factors with multivariate analyses model (GAM beta inflated)?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, beta-regression, gamlss, prevalence

While analizing the prevalence of cows to brucellosis (illness), and in order to relate it to a set of factors like country, state, and detection technique, I need to apply a multivariate analysis method. Here I share a [simulation of the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nM9VXB9dpGuxUCZYaXQS0vAwxOM70BVJn1ThDdzXIn8/edit?usp=sharing).

The prevalence variable follow a beta(0.3238, 0.7555) distribution, as ceiling and floor conditions and a Cullen-Frey plot suggests, and its parameters were determined by likelihood methods (MGE). a) *Is this fact evidence enough to apply a GAM model?*

- If yes, b) is a **GAM beta model zero and one inflated** adjusted a good approach to asses **which levels are more related to prevalence**?

This is the proposed model:

```
df <- read_excel("vacows.xlsx")
mod2 <- gamlss(
prevalencia ~ s(country)+s(year)+s(state)+s(technique)+s(species)+s(patogen)+s(use),
sigma.formula = ~ 1,
nu.formula = ~ 1,
tau.formula = ~ 1,
family=BEINF,
method = RS(),
data=df)
```

In this case, summary(mod2) gives a table of p-values. Are the most important levels those with p<0.05?

- If no, c) is a GLM model over a transformation of the prevalence (e.g. cox-box) a good alternative?